# Differences between "apache"'s installations

Tags: apache-2.2, installation, apt, ubuntu-12.04

Using Ubuntu 12.04, are there any differences between installing **Apache httpd** using `sudo apt-get install apache2` (as the guide of Ubuntu says - https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html
) or following the steps on the Apache documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html#overview)?

I tried both ways; in the first case (using `apt-get`) the server seems to work - I open a browser page and I got it. In the second case I need other packages (*apr*, *apr-util* and *pcre*) and so I abandoned the attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way you did the install was using packaged and precompiled version of apache provided by your linux distribution that cares about dependencies and automatically install needed packages for apache to work.

The second way you did the install was using source code provided by apache foundation and you have to care your self for dependencies according to the manual recommendation/requirements.

Unless you need a particular version of the server, I recommand you stick to the version provided by your linux distribution, it's easier and it will avoid you the hassle of taking care about dependencies, patches and updates.

Answer (score 1):

You should generally install your software from repository packages rather than from source. Installing software from packages automatically resolves dependency issues, all files are kept in the right place and it's more easy to update the software.
Install software from source if your linux distro doesn't support version of software that you need to use. That way you'll need to resolve all dependency issues manually.